# How to extend the Page class from Symfony simple cms bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I'm trying to [extend the default Page class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/simple_cms/extending_page_class.html) from symfony simple cms bundle.

**The problem:**
The custom property is not persisted.

Below is the code of the class which extends from BasePage.

```
use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Annotations\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Annotations as PHPCRODM;
use Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\SimpleCmsBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Page as BasePage;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @PHPCRODM\Document(referenceable=true)
 */
class Product extends BasePage
{
    public $node;

    /**
     * @var string(nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

   /**
    * Get Code
    * @return string
    */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code; 
    }

   /**
    * Set code
    * @return Product
    */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        return $this;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks almost correct, but you miss a mapping on the $code:

```
/**
 * @PHPCRODM\String(nullable=true)
 */
private $code;
```

I assume that `$code` is not language dependant. Otherwise you would need `nullable=true,translatable=true`

If you also want to have the PHPCR node mapped, you need

```
/**
 * @PHPCRODM\Node
 */
public $node;
```